# Cannot see the points in my scatter plot despite having R value

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scatter-plot

I am facing this exact same issue. I am using a csv file with the missing rows dropped to make my scatter plot. I have also use matplotlib yet I am getting not output despite having the R value.

```
mc_corr=cars2_1["City_Mileage_km_litre"].corr(cars2_1['Fuel_Tank_Capacity_litre'])
plt.scatter(cars2_1["City_Mileage_km_litre"],cars2_1['Fuel_Tank_Capacity_litre'],color='orange')
plt.title('Mileage vs Fuel Tank Capacity')
plt.xlim(5,35)
plt.ylim(3.5,10.0)
plt.xlabel("R = "+str(mc_corr))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

The data set:

[image: Input]

Comment: can you put link of dataset?

Comment: I just realised that ylim was too small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ylim is too short for values to fall into, change:

```
plt.ylim(3.5,10.0)
```

to

```
plt.ylim(24,88)
```

Comment: Man, I should smack my head against the wall.

Comment: bugs are there for us to solve, take it easy

Comment: Hi, if my answer help you solve the problem, it should be marked as answer for this question to be closed